# Problems connecting to a basicHttpBinding endpoint with security mode="None"

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, basichttpbinding

Trying to create an framework 4.0 WCF basicHttp service hosted by IIS (6) that is completely unauthenticated. Once deployed, I can successfully retrive the WSDL via a browser.

However whenever I try and connect to it via WCF Test Client or via a visual studio generated proxy, I'm getting "The server has rejected the client credentials.".

This still occurs when I add `<security mode="None"/>`, but my understanding is that this is the default anyway ...

In the IIS virtual directory properties I only have anonymous ticked, and in the web.config file `<authentication mode="None"/>` is set as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you refresh the service reference everytime you made a change to the WCF service in IIS?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty careful to refresh the service reference every time I make a change.

Comment: Show whole service configuration.

Comment: To be honest, I've ended up removing most of of the previous configuration (and get the same error) since it's WCF framework 4, and I believe it now works most of this out for us - right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the source of the exception was from an immediate attempt to connect to a downstream tcp service.  As a workaround I ended up creating a plain jane webservice wrapper which successfully connects to the downstream service fine using a domain account specified in the `<identity impersonate="true" userName=".." password=".." />`.

Note, I've added a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265617/problems-connecting-to-an-authenticed-downstream-nettcp-endpoint) asking why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the IIS site has anonymous authentication disabled. Check out this [article on IIS 6 anonymous access](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f594e137-e2da-4b22-ab58-f8edba938802.mspx?mfr=true) configuration.

Comment: Have checked "Anonymous access" checkbox in IIS virtual directory.