# Problems connecting to an authenticated downstream netTcp endpoint

Tags: wcf, impersonation, delegation

In a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197166/problems-connecting-to-a-basichttpbinding-endpoint-with-security-mode-none), I am having trouble connecting to a basicHttp endpoint and it seems that it is due to WCF impersonation issues when connecting to a downstream service.  The funny thing is that it works fine when I replace the basicHttp WCF service with an ASMX web service.  Both services use `<identity impersonate="true" userName=".." password=".." />` from ASP.NET web.config file, but the ASMX service works while the basicHttp WCF service doesn't.

Does this seem likely to be some sort if Kerberos delegation issue between ASP.NET and WCF?
Or is there something that I can add to my WCF configuration to pass this impersonated user (note I am using framework 4, so I currently have almost no configurtation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked out that I needed to add `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>` to the WCF part of the web.config file, and an [AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsmode.aspx) attribute to the implementation of the basicHttp endpoint.  This will then call the downstream netTcp endpoint using the credentials defined in `<identity impersonate="true" userName=".." password=".." />`.